# Where should my Quiz model get 'instantiated'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I might (still) be thinking about this in the wrong way, but I'm hitting an error that says

`"Couldn't find Quiz with 'id'=39"`

The line that generates this error is:

```
if (Quiz.find(current_user.id)) 
...
```

I think there are 2 problems with this code:

1) The Quiz table has a user_id column that associates it with a User, but I'm (unintentionally) looking for the ID of the quiz.
2) The Quiz never gets instantiated so, even if I looked for the user_id attribute in Quiz, there would be no Quiz to find.

I'd like to know where in my Rails code I should create the Quiz in the first place. Is this something that should happen when a User is created? If so, should the Quiz be instantiated 'in' a @quiz variable in User? And in which method? new? build? initialize? create?

This instantiation, I assume, would need to include setting the new Quiz's user_id to the current_user.id, so I don't see how that can happen in the model, before current_user is even accessible.

Any clues, much appreciated.

BTW, User `has_one :quiz` and Quiz `belongs_to :user`

Comment: Why not `User.quiz`? You might want to take a step back and spin through some basic RoR tutorials real quick, this is basic Rails functionality and is pretty well documented.

Comment: Because, at the moment, there's no Quiz created on User. Would that be 'best practise' or is it just one of several ways of doing it?

Comment: A `@quiz` variable would not be persisted; that's an instance variable, which is different from an ActiveRecord-managed value.

Comment: Hmm... I think I'm having a hard time disentangling the `has_one` association and the idea of an instance variable. I'm used to instance variables persisting with instances. This must work differently. I've been tutorialing a lot, but there's a lot to be sure about at one time - and getting 'sure' about each piece is pretty hard when I'm not exactly sure about what I think I've sorted out already. Yes, it's maddening.

Comment: Also - can I ask again - If not an instance variable, where would the Quiz be created? Is there a line of code I need to add, or does Rails just do that magically because of the `has_one` association?

Comment: It won't create an instance magically; you must create it (there are many ways to do so, recent tutorials should demonstrate, and IIRC the rails docs on associations does as well). An instance variable in an AR class lives outside the persistence model; this is one reason why you must use the `self.foo = bar` when assigning a value to be persisted (and the column must exist in the DB, obviously)--neither `foo = bar` will work (local variable) nor `@foo = bar` (instance variable) because of how AR "taps in" to Ruby to do its work.

Comment: I have been reading pages and pages of the guides and tutorials, but it is hard to know which specific piece of information applies in a specific situation. I know it might seem like I'm just asking for 'the code', but if you could tell me how it should be done in the case I describe above, I should understand it and be able to use it in other cases. I'd appreciate it. In the mean time I'll take another look at the IIRC (whatever that is - hello google...)

Comment: OK, turns out IIRC stands for If I Recall Correctly. Just so you know...

Comment: Fer's answer using `build_quiz` already supplies what I'd call the canonical method, but setting the `user_id` manually will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your Quiz in several ways:

- `Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id)`
- `current_user.quiz`

If you use Quiz.find(5) (and that is what in the end your `Quiz.find(current_user.id)`, what you are doing is to search for the Quizz with id = 5

You can create your Quiz as follows:

Though the user:

`@quiz = current_user.build_quiz attribute_hash`

or

`@quiz = Quizz.new user_id: current_user.id, other: :attributes`

and then `@quiz.save`

Comment: Yeah, that was the first problem I mentioned above. I'll try the .where method...

Comment: The real problem is the SECOND problem I mentioned. Where should my Quiz be instantiated? I'm getting an error saying the @quiz I'm passing to my form is nil. I'm using `@quiz = Quiz.create(user_id: current_user.id)` in my QuizzesController

Comment: The flow usually is the following: You controller receives the `new` request. That action instantiates `@quiz = Quiz.new` or `current_user.build_quiz`, and then the view is displayed. Typically this will show the form to the user, where the user can add the data and then submit the form, which will be sent to the `create` action. In this case you instantiate `@quiz.current_user.quiz params[:quiz]` (this depends on rails version) and then you can call @quiz.save. If the validation passes, the quiz will be saved in the database. If not, yo have to render the `new` view again

Comment: I'm getting a new error - when I click the 'submit' button on my form it's looking for the 'update' action. This is news to me because I thought submit buttons linked to 'create'. Oh well. But I think what I'm doing with `@quiz = Quiz.create(user_id: current_user.id)` seems to be creating the Quiz. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: If it is leading to the update is because you already saved the quiz into the database. Rails look at that and chooses the right HTTP method to be used in the form. Be sure that in the `new` action method you are calling to `Quiz.new` and not to the `Quiz.create` method. For further problems, ask new questions (after searching first). That is beyond the scope of your current question (this is a comments section, not a chat)